# Calling inherited method in Java

Tags: java

I have the following java code,

```
class Animal {
    private String name="Animal";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    private String name = "Cat";
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat cat = new Cat();
        System.out.println(cat.getName());
    }
}
```

after running that code, I got output `Animal`, but I think it should be `Cat`. And after overriding `getName` method in `Cat` like this, I got `Cat`.

```
@Override
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

Is that because calling an inherited (not overrode) method in a subclass  instance just like  `cat.getName()`  equals to calling `super.getName()` (so I get `Animal` instead of `Cat` in the first case)? Or because the strange behavior of instance variable hiding (I'm not very sure)?

Comment: You need to override the `getName` method

Comment: MadProgrammer answered your last question, yes, you did not override that method

Comment: @MadProgrammer  If not overriding `getName`, when I call `getName` on cat, is that equals to call `super.getName()`(I meant calling `getName` of `Animal`)?

Comment: The purpose of Method Overriding is clear here. Child class wants to give its own implementation so that when it calls this method, it prints Cat instead of Animal.

Comment: @jack_lv yes since cat is the subclass of Animal

Comment: In Java, only method can be overridden, not member fields.  There is no mechanism to do late binding for member field lookup in Java.

Comment: In Java, variables are not polymorphic, they do not override one another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `name` field is redeclared in the child class, but with the method `getName` being implemented in the parent, the only field that's going to be read is the parent's, `Animal.name`.

It's always a bad idea to declare in subclasses fields that have been declared in the superclass, because fields don't get "overridden", they're simply hidden.

What you intended to do is either of the following:

**Override the method:**

```
class Animal {
    private String name="Animal";

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    public String getName() {
        return "Cat";
    }
}
```

You can also declare a different field in the subclass, but that would be a bad idea still. The "proper" way to do that is overriding the method.

Or, **expose the field to subclasse**s, and change the value from the child class:

```
class Animal {
    protected String name = "Animal";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    public Cat() {
        this.name = "Cat";
    }
}
```

This way, there's no confusion about which field stores the actual value, and it's clear where the "overriding" happens.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a private scope variable with the same name in the Cat class does nothing to obscure the variable in the Animal class. To change the behavior you need to override the accessor method to read the variable from the Cat class context.

Answer (score 0):

You can overload methods, not data members. `Animal.name` and `Cat.name` are two different data members. There's nothing special about `Animal.getName()` - it returns `Animal.name`, and is completely unaware of `Cat.name`.

One possible approach is to have just one data member, `Animal.name`, and have each class initialize it differently. E.g:

```
class Animal {
    private String name;

    public Animal() {
        this("Animal);
    }

    protected Animal(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    public Cat() {
        this("Cat');
    }
}
```

Or if you want to rely on your class names, you could just use `getSimpleName`:

```
class Animal {
    private String name;

    public Animal() {
        name = getClass().getSimpleName();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `cat.getName()` calls the `getName()` method in `Animal` class that knows only *its own* `name` field, not subclasses one.

A possible solution could be:

```
class Animal {
    private String name = "Animal";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    private String name = "Cat";

    public Cat() {
        setName(name);    
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat cat = new Cat();
        System.out.println(cat.getName());
    }
}
```

I discourage you to override method because you should do it on every future `Animal` subclass.

Answer (score 0):

> you need to override the method getName(). it's instance level
>   function you can call it in child class but you cannot modify it
>   without overriding the function. So it's calling parent class function
>   with parent class property.
>
> just override the method if you want "cat" in output.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer covers some good answers, but I wanted to add a few things.

1. I would discourage adding an overrided getName method in the Cat Class if you are doing the exact same thing. This is to prevent code duplication in any other subclasses you may create.
2. You could create a constructor to initialize the name field instead and switch the name field to protected.

Eg.

```
class Animal {
    protected String name;

    public Animal() {
        this.name = "Animal";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    public Cat() {
        this.name = "Cat";
    }
}
```

3. Alternatively, if you want to keep the name field private, you could create a setter method that's protected to allow only your subclasses to set the name.

Eg.

```
class Animal {
    private String name = "Animal";

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    protected void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    public Cat() {
        setName("Cat");
    }
}
```